# Using read() and putting the buffer into a string

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy, atoi

this is my second question as i've had trouble with the first one due to this problem.
I have a file which i have to read using the read() statment, no no fget() or fread() etc
i use the line.

```
read(fileRead, buffer, blocksize);
```

where as you know fileRead is my filedescriptor, buffer is an unsigned char and blocksize is the size of buffer (i chose 32);
my problem is i have a loop which runs until the file ends and takes a buffer of the file (32) and i need to put that into a string.

So i was wondering if you could help me with the line of code which would take the buffer and append it to a string (not 2D array, this won't be good)
I have tried

```
openCopyClose(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i=0,j=0, k=0, count = 0;
    size_t blocksize = 32;
    char fromFile[256], newFile[1000][100], string[100000];
    int fileRead;
    unsigned char buffer[blocksize];
    ssize_t status;

    strcpy(fromFile, argv[1]);

    fileRead = open(fromFile, O_RDONLY);  // open for reading

    status = 99;
    while (status > 1)        //while not EOF or error
    {
        status = read(fileRead, buffer, blocksize);
        strcpy(newFile[i], buffer);

        for(count = 0; count<= 32; count++)
        {
            buffer[count] = 0;
        }
        i ++;                   

        if(status < 0)
        {
            printf("oops2\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    printf("\n");

    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%s", newFile[j]);
    }          
    close(fileRead);

}
```

But this will not work when i try to strtok it to put it in a structure. **I need that file into one string using read()** any ideas?

my code for the strtok afterwards will need to look something like this

```
struct processStruct processes[700];
while(count < 701)
{

    processes[count].processNumber = strtok(newFile[0], " \n");
    processes[count].quanta = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));
    processes[count].priority = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));

    count ++;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Are you sure your data line is 32 byte long? Show us the file being parsed.

Comment: I'm passing the file through the read command read(fileRead, buffer, blocksize) blocksize is 32, is that what you wanted? my problem is putting 'buffer' into a single string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved how to put the File into a string, it was relatively simple, i'm surprised i missed it

```
for(k =0; k < sizeof(buffer); k++)
{
    newFile[i] = buffer[k];
    i++;
 }
```

and now to put it in the struct.....

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark to the left so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~